# Swift 2 - completion block syntax when using in Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have this Swift block:

```
var onLoggedIn: ((sender:AnyObject?, showFTUE:Bool) -> ())?
```

Trying to use it in Obj-C, and XCode 7 autocompletes as:

```
 [loginController setOnLoggedIn:^(id _Nullable, BOOL) {
        <#code#>
    }];
```

But then throws an error and tells me `parameter name is omitted`. I tried inserted the parameter `showFTUE` in various positions with no luck.

In my Swift translation file it's translated as:

---

---

Comment: to clarify, you've tried `^(id _Nullable, BOOL showFTUE)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Xcode 7, when your completion block declared in .h (in obj-c) doesn't have names (which is default autocomplete behavior from Xcode 7) it will also autocomplete without parameter names. As you can see your block has only types and _Nullable directive, just add parameter names at the end.

```
[loginController setOnLoggedIn:^(id _Nullable parameterName1, BOOL parameterName1) {
        <#code#>
}];
```